# Django 2.0 Tutorial - AttributeError at /polls/1/vote/ 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I've come across this error on SE before, but it tends to be for previous versions of Django - and I don't have a good understanding of how Django works. I've made it to part 4 of the tutorial, and it was working up until this tutorial. I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong - most of this is copy/pasted from the tutorial at this point to see if that would make it work. I'm not exactly python saavy so if someone could explain the problem in fairly simple english I would appreciate it. I know the issue has something to do w/ line 30 in veiws, in the "vote" section -

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    try:
        selected_choice = Question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Thanks SE.

**error code:**

```
AttributeError at /polls/1/vote/
'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/1/vote/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/mysite2/mysite3/polls/views.py in vote, line 30
Python Executable:  /Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/mysite2/mysite3',
 '/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 26 May 2018 03:16:49 +0000


Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/1/vote/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls.apps.PollsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env1/mysite2/mysite3/polls/views.py" in vote
  30.         selected_choice = Question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/1/vote/
Exception Value: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**heres my code for the various files:**

polls/urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/veiws:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/details.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    try:
        selected_choice = Question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

polls/admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
polls/urls:

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/templates/polls/details.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

polls/templates/polls/results.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
polls/templates/polls/index.html:

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

mysite/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite3 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*8a@se$l_8v%(-xyz=!!=jgvyjyn611zqw(dqroejvkk^o9%co'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite3.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite3.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line throwing the error:

`selected_choice = Question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])`

Basically, you need to call `choice_set` on an **instance** of the Question model, not on the model itself.

So something like this might work:

```
question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
```